# How to provide pagination in filtered data for distinct column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbctemplate, postgresql-9.5

I need to provide a list of 10 distinct values of a column in a table .

```
select distinct a from table order by a offset :pageNumber rows fetch next 10 rows only;
```

but this provides the distinct values of column 'a' for the 10 rows of table depending on the pageNumber. So instead of 10 distinct values I get less than 10 and even when the pageNumber increases I might get the same distinct values as before as it paginates the rows in table . I need to put pagination on the distinct values itself . Postgres Version being used 9.5.

I need 10 distinct values on every execution of this query not the distinct values of column 'a' from the 10 rows .

How do I provide pagination for the distinct column .

Comment: "So instead of 10 distinct values I get less than 10"  I can't reproduce this, unless there are fewer than `:pageNumber + 10` distinct values present in the first place.

Comment: "I might get the same distinct values as before"  In the absence of an ORDER BY, you don't get to complain about what order it returns things in, or if it chooses a different order from query to query.  That said, I can't reproduce this either.

Comment: @jjanes Even if I add order by I still cannot control the number of distinct values I get from the column 'a'. I want first 10 distinct values not the distinct values present in first 10 rows .

Comment: You have to show what you are actually doing.  Your new query gives `ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can't reproduce your issue either... but if you are experiencing what you claim then you might be able to get around it using `with`.

```
 with dist_a as (
  select distinct a from table
 )
 select a from dist_a order by a offset (:pageNumber*10) rows fetch next 10 rows only;
```